# How to search references with Eclipse IDE in spring xml files?

Tags: eclipse, spring

- I have some beans defined in Java classes
- Those beans are instantiated and used in spring xml files.

Question: With Eclipse it is quite comfortable to do a F3 ("Open Declaration") to find the class implementing the method I'm interested in. How would I do that in a spring xml file?

E.g. I have something like this here:

```
<spring:bean id="myInstance" class="com.example.MyClass" init-method="init">
    <property name="host">
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property name="port">
        <value>8080</value>
    </property>
</spring:bean>
```

It would be nice if I could click on "port" and get directed to the method "setPort" and the class that implements it.

It would be even more awesome if I could to a search references in Eclipse that also shows all those spring xml files where setPort is used.

Are there plugins, etc. for Eclipse that allow me to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have STS installed on top of eclipse and it does exactly what you want.  I hold the CTRL key down, click on the property name and the IDE will take me to the setter on the class.

One exception is that it does not work when using the 'p' notation in your xml.

```
<bean class="someClass" p:someProperty="foo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I highlight the string to search for then use `<ctrl> h`, then use the `File Search` tab with the filename pattern of `*.xml`.  Clunky but works.  FYI `<ctrl> + <shift> + r` opens a resource or file within your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Indigo has this feature built in.

If you F3 on `com.example.MyClass` you'll be taken to the definition of the class. Scroll down to the method you wish to know about. Right click on the method name, go to the `References` menu and select `Workspace`.

On OSX, the if you highlight the method name, the keyboard shortcut is Shift-Command-G

Answer (score 0):

So if you have setup Spring Project then you can install **STS plugin** and if you press F3 on any name in XML it will help you lead to its declaration. Refer link http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/STS for more details.

Worked for me.